# Android application on device

Tags: android

I wrote some application and installed it on tablet.
Than I needed to create some other application with some other features.
I changed my first application name and I changed some part of codes.
But when I installed the new app on my tablet it deleted my first application in some words it overwrites my first app.
I find some way (to change main package name too) but I don't want to do it.
Do you have any idea how to avoid this kind of situation?

Comment: you want to make a "new app" that doesn't overwrite the old one without changing the name/package???
How to avoid: if it's different app, rename it...

Comment: You need to change package name!

Comment: jmp I renamed it but it overwrites it every time!!!

Comment: David_D my question is : is there the other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the application package name if you want Android to recognize it as a different app. Android's internal logic is that same package name = same app, and installing one will replace the other.

Then again, I don't see why changing the package name would be painful. It's generally a good idea to use different package names for different apps. You don't need to change package names for classes inside the app, though.

When changing the package name in Eclipse, be sure to use *Android Tools > Rename application package* from the menu. Just editing `AndroidManifest.xml` will not work and give you weird effects (a lesson I painfully learned). Eclipse will guide you through this and make the necessary adjustments to your code.

Comment: it isn't painful.
I just want to know is there any other solution?

Comment: I'm afraid not. `com.example.myapp` on Android is like `c:\windows\notepad.exe` on Windows. Copy another executable named `notepad.exe` into `c:\windows`, and it will replace what is there.